# Best practise to realize up down arrows in select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the best way to setup a percentage arrow up/down slider/selector in a select element in a web page like this:

[image: up down arrow slider for percentage]

1. A select list with a dedicated background. If yes, how can it be detected that the user clicked on the up or down arrows?
2. Build for each percentage up/down item a table of three rows/one column with: a) row 1 = up arrow, b) row 2 = select option list, c) row 3 = down arrow
3. some other solution?

Remark: the percentages can be increased/decreased in steps of 5 %

Comment: Is expected result of clicking arrows only to increase or decrease value?

Comment: show what you tried

Comment: @guest271314: clicking arrows should increase/decrease values, yes. Additionally, an onchange event should enable a call to a javascript function.

Comment: @jafarbtech: so far I did not try anything, as I want to know best practices in such a situation.

Comment: In the 3 second video I uploaded to youtube, you can see that if I click  the up arrows appr. 4 times a second, there is a selection effect. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTRVY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<input type="number">` element, `<label>` elements, `css` `:before`, `:after`, `input` event to handle click on `input type="number"` element, custom event to handle clicks on `label` elements.

```js
$("label[for]").on("click", function(event) {
  $("#input").val(function(_, n) {
    return event.target.htmlFor === "up" 
           ? +n < +this.max ? +n + 5 : n 
           : +n > +this.min ? +n - 5 : n;
  }).trigger("arrow")
});

$("#input").on("input arrow", function(event) {
  if (event.isTrigger) {
    console.log("arrow");
  } else {
    console.log("input")
  }
  console.log(this.value + "%")
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
 div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
input[type="number"] {
  width: 45px;
  outline: thin solid navy;
}
label[for="up"]:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: "\25B2";
  top: -20px !important;
  left: 32.5px;
  position: relative;
}
label[for="down"]:before {
  content: "\25BC";
  position: relative;
  top: 20px !important;
  left: -32.5px;
}
label[for="down"]:after {
  content: "%";
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="select1">
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
  </select>
  <label for="up"></label><input id="input" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="0"><label for="down"></label>
</div>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: just one question remains: clicking fast in Chrome (Ubuntu) makes strange selections of the web contents. This does not appear in Firefox@Ubuntu. See: [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rntq0o0nFc0

Comment: @user2145488 Not certain what video is intended to convey?

Comment: the video just shows the behaviour I mentioned: if I click quickly on the "up" arrow, the selections are visible.

Comment: What do you mean by "the selections are visible"?

Comment: In the 3 second video I uploaded to youtube, you can see that if I click  the up arrows appr. 4 times a second, there is for every second or third click a selection of several parts of the html elements (like "abc", the percent value itself etc.). See screenshot:  [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTRVY.png

Comment: That appears to be the element gaining focus.

Comment: ok, and what can I do to avoid it? As it seems to be a timing topic: would it help to ignore mouse clicks for some milliseconds?

Comment: @user2145488 Would suggest asking Question specific to that topic including description of issue and expected result within body of Question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve